# read only class member C++

Tags: c++, getter, getter-setter

I'm a bit confused I read that there are some downsides using getters and setters in C++ although to create a read only variable, making the variable private and creating a getter function seems like the obvious thing to do.
Maybe there is a simple answer and I'm just not able to see it, but what would be a good/better alternative to make a member variable read only without a getter or is using a getter function acceptable or even good solution for this problem?

Comment: I don't know what you read, but classes are better designed in terms of what they do, as opposed to what they have. A class that's simply a lump of data with getters and setters is an anti-pattern.

Comment: See also the "Tell, don't ask" principle at http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html

Answer (score 2):

a) providing getters and setters and/or b) public data attributes

defeat the software engineering goals of achieving optimal coupling and cohesion.

---

From Wikipedia:

> In software engineering, coupling is the manner and degree of
> interdependence between software modules; a measure of how closely
> connected two routines or modules are; the strength of the
> relationships between modules. Coupling is usually contrasted with
> cohesion.
>
> In computer programming, cohesion refers to the degree to which the
> elements of a module belong together.[1] Thus, cohesion measures the
> strength of relationship between pieces of functionality within a
> given module. For example, in highly cohesive systems functionality is
> strongly related.

---

In procedural programming, there are (typically) 8 levels of coupling that are ranked (worst to best).  The wiki article describes all of them. Your coding efforts should strive for the best coupling (with label 'none').

There are (typically) 7 levels of cohesion that are ranked (worst to best).  You should strive for the best cohesion (with label 'functional').

---

One way to think about coupling - if you add setters and getter or use public data attributes, why did you bother encapsulating those data into this class at all?  If you allow the data attributes to be modified by any part of the code, then think how much non-class code might need to change when requirements changes force you change the name and/or type of a data attribute.

The similar thought about cohesion -- with public data attributes so easily modified by unrelated code (code in another object or external function), what makes them a 'good choice' to be a part of your class?  Perhaps these 'external' codes should be part of your object ... are the data related to the primary 'goals' of what this object does for the system.

Comment: But if you *do* have an  attribute of a class that you want to be visible outside the class ((for example, `vector.size`, then private member variable(s) and a public getter member function is the right way to do it.

Comment: Could you link to the Wikipedia article you quote?

Comment: @MartinBonner - If you think there is an attribute you want to cherry pick to pull out of the instance, ask yourself a) how you want to use it, and b) should / could the code/method/function using this info be moved inside the instance?  But yeah, I have sometimes made the same decision (a public getter),

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a const reference to the variables. This is the only time when I use a naming convention by prefixing read-only private variables with an '_'.

You can also use the reference variable throughout the class if you’re only reading it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;

struct Vector2 {
    float X, Y;

    // this creates a const reference so you can only read from it
    const float& Magnitude = _Magnitude;
    
    Vector2(float x = 0.0f, float y = 0.0f): X(x), Y(y) {
        // when you need to write to it use the private variable
        _Magnitude = sqrt(
            X * X +
            Y * Y
        );
    }
    
private:
   float _Magnitude = 0.0f; 
};

int main() {
    
    Vector2 pos(10, 20);
    
    // reading the value is fine
    cout << pos.Magnitude << '\n';
    
    // writing to it will cause an error
    //pos.Magnitude = 6.0f;
    
}
```